# Finding $(\mathrm A \times \mathrm B)^c$ ($\mathrm X^{\mathrm c}$ denotes complement of $\mathrm X$)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For sets $\mathrm A$ and $\mathrm B$, find $$(\mathrm A \times \mathrm B)^{\mathrm c}$$
$\big(\mathrm X^{\mathrm c}$ denotes complement of $\mathrm X \big)$

I literally have no idea how to 'open' the bracket, I am having a hard time with these kind of problems. We're supposed to simplify the above problem in the form of $\mathrm A, \mathrm B, \mathrm A^{\mathrm c}$ and $\mathrm B^{\mathrm c}$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(A\times B)^{c}=(A^{c}\times B^{c})\cup(A^{c}\times B)\cup(A\times B^{c})$. The philosophy is that, if $(a,b)$ does not belong to $A\times B$, then either $a$ does not belong to $A$ or $b$ does not belong to $B$ or both cases to be held true.